# is a plane smooth surface?

Tags: differential-geometry

let f(u,v)=a + u.p + v.q  : the equation of the plane

where p,q are unit vectors perpendicular to each other. a a point on the plane.

I do not understand how f can have partial derivatives of all orders, since derivative of wrt. u and v are p and q, respectively.
after this, aren't the derivatives zero?

Comment: What prevents zero from being a derivative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second order and higher partial derivatives of $f$ are indeed $0$, which is not a problem.

The zero function has partial derivatives of all orders.